# JSON Parsing non-english characters

Tags: android, html, json, parsing, utf-8

[image]

I am trying to learn parsing data from a url to my app by using this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/. I imported the project. It is working. This project is using this url source. 
http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/

Then i decided to test the project by changing its url values. For example i wanted to change the names. I have no experience on html or php. So i created a website by using free web hosting. Then i opened the androidhive url ,copied everything inside the page and then uploaded to my new web site.I copied all the datas to index.html file. Then i modified the code by changing the url. Instead of using this >

```
 private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";
```

i changed the url to my website. At first it was working . My app was parsing the data and showing the results. But there was a problem. Non_english characters were not as they are.As you can see from the pictures , when i write some characters such as "İÜÇÖĞ..." to my index html and upload to my website they were displaying as the first picture.You can see the corrupted letters from the first line. So the app was parsing the string as it was displayed in the first picture . That is not what i wanted. While creating this index.html i choosed"UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM" in the notepad++.

Then i tried another thing.I uploaded the same thing by using "UTF-8" in notepad++.The results were seen in second picture. The letters were ok ,this was what i wanted to see. But parsing is not working now.When i run the project there is nothing in the screen.It displays just an empty white page. What should i change from the android side or html side to display the letters correct?

Comment: There are a number of things this could be. When you're sending the web request are you setting the charset to UTF-8? Does the typeface you're using support international characters? Is the server set to return something different than UTF-8?

Comment: Yes in android side of the project the params are getting with utf-8. You can see in the link.What is needed to change ?

Comment: The BOM is probably confusing your parser but not the web browser. Have you set the mime type for your contact list hosted by your server?

Comment: You may also want to force decoding of your HTTP response to use UTF-8 with: `response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8");`